# Thunar bug? Should i report to Xfce or Ubuntu?

Tags: xfce, xubuntu, thunar

Start up with farily slow, then file manager won't open, and nothing thunar related will work.

I get the error message when i try to shut down my PC through GUI.

```
"GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs:Type of message, "(yb)", does not match expected type"(b)"
```

However, if i use

```
pkill thunar
```

It works fine flawlessly.

Thunar bug? Should i report to Xfce or Ubuntu?

Comment: You can try to ask here first  [xfce-forum](https://forum.xfce.org/)

Comment: @ctac_thanks already filed a bug

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to clear the session cache, like proposed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/xfce/comments/bej4xx/received_error_while_trying_to_log_out/) ?

> open Settings Manager -> Session and Startup -> Session -> Clear saved
> sessions

Or more direct: `rm -rf ~/.cache/sessions`